# Jsoup .data() inside loop

Tags: java, android, arrays, jsoup

I have a probably quite easy-to-answer question, but I just couldn't find an answer :/

If I connect to a site via jsoup, and want to modify a form in order to submit it by:

```
upload_doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .cookies(loginCookies)

                    .data(check_radio_yes_name[0], "1") ...
```

How can I loop the Array inside .data() ? It seems like I can't just insert a for() loop before closing with `.get();`, so what's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [jsoup's apidoc](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#data-java.util.Map-) you can send collections with `data`, so you can do something like this:

```
Map<String, String> myData = new HashMap<String, String>();
String key = "check_radio_yes_name[";
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    myData.put(key + i + "]", "1");  //add your data instead of "1"
upload_doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .cookies(loginCookies)
                .data(myData)...
```

Define all your data in a map, and then add the entire map.